# Sonar will not save analysis to database based on date value

Tags: database, date, jenkins, sonarqube

On a Jenkins server, I have a need to save some sonar runs of a java project that spans multiple revisions. This is working perfectly so far until I try to run on certain older revisions of the code. I've found if I set the Project Properties value sonar.projectDate to around somewhere in the years of 2006-2007 (the oldest code I have originates from there), Sonar will not save the run. However, Jenkins console output is an exact match between successful runs and failure runs (both even declare SUCCESS at the bottom). Unfortunately, it is not present on the Dashboard, but should I modify the date to something more recent, even in the future, say 2020, Sonar will save this data perfectly and it will indeed show up in the dashboard.

Anyone else with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, this has to deal with how Sonar's default behavior is for saving and killing off snapshots (instances of measuring the codebase). By default, snapshots are only saved in the best case for up to 5 years, which if you set the date on a codebase's snapshot that is past that 5 year maximum, it will be ignored.